# if statement mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, join

[image: stock erd]

I am trying to figure out how to do an if statement that will essentially calculate the stock of an item based on the dates in the tp_rental table.
I was hoping to do something like :

if Date_Due has an entry but Date_Returned does not
then set stock -1

if Date_Due has an entry and Date_returned has an entry entered
then set stock +1

See below for my attempt, not sure if i need a join here?

```
update title_platform
set Stock = case
    when tp_rental.Date_Returned is not null then stock -1
    else stock +1
end
```

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Please read up https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: Try building up the LEFT JOIN  you want between the items and the leases. Chances are that you only need to SUM(IF(Date IS NULL, 1, 0)) and group by the item ID. If an item has been leased five times and only has three returns, then 2 is the number of outstanding items to be taken out of stock, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an UPDATE statement with a join between the 2 tables and a CASE expression:

```
update title_platform p inner join tp_rental r
on r.platformid = p.platformid
set p.stock = p.stock + case
  when r.date_due is not null and r.date_returned is null then -1
  when r.date_due is not null and r.date_returned is not null then 1
  else ? -- if there is another option
end
```

Remove the `else` part if it is not needed.
Edit: if there are multiple rows in `tp_rental` for each `platformid` then you must aggregate first and then join:

```
update title_platform p inner join (
  select platformid, 
    sum(date_due is not null and date_returned is not null) -  
    sum(date_due is not null and date_returned is null) result
  from tp_rental
  group by platformid
) r on r.platformid = p.platformid
set p.stock = case
  when p.stock + r.result < 0 then 0
  else p.stock + r.result
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked. Do you know how i would set the stock minimum to be 0 as after running that query some have went to -1 rather than 0
thank you

Comment: Just to clarify, are there multiple rows in tp_rental for each platformid?

Comment: yes there are, there will be multiple rows for platformid titleid and rentalID, using the 3 as a composite PK